# What is "=" in transcriptions of Hittite

Tags: transcription, notation, hittite

I have not yet seen this double-hyphen explained, which is written eg. in *An Etymological Dictionary Of The Hittite Inherited Lexicon* (Kloekhorsts 2007)

> *-a* (3rd.sg.pres.midd.-ending): see *-a(ri)*
>
> *=a* 'and, too': see *=(i̯)a
>
> *=a* 'but': see *=(m)a*
>
> *=a-* (enclitic pronoun) 'he, she, it': […; pg. 196-198]

What's the difference from *=* to the usual hyphenation marking morpheme boundaries?

> […] The forms *[n]=e-e=n* (KBo 17.1 KBo 25.3 i 20 (OS)) and *[n=e-e=]n* (StBoT 25.4 i 15 (OS)) seem to show that […; pg. 208-209]

Wow, that's most cryptic. The question should be however easy to answer without detours into grammar (otherwise, pending own research, I would revise the question). Is the difference just *ending* versus *enclitic*?

How specialized is this, certainly not exclusive to Hittite studies?!

Comment: Note that Kloekhorst (p. xiii) glosses = as "morpheme boundary", which is rather misleading.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your guess is correct; the equals sign/double hyphen separates clitics from the words they attach to.

For example, from the *Ten-Year Annals* (KBo 3.4 ii 65):

> *nu=us=si=kan widār arha dahhun*
>   Then I took away the waters there.

```
nu  =us     =si     =kan widār        arha da  -hhun  
then=3PL.ACC=3SG.LOC=MOD water.ACC.PL away take-1.SG.PAST
```

This isn't exclusive to Hittite; it's actually part of the Leipzig glossing conventions (rule 2). It's just very prevalent in Hittite because Hittite uses a *lot* of enclitics—most sentences will have at least one, and four or five isn't unusual.

(Some sources, including the Chicago Hittite Dictionary, use a double oblique hyphen (⸗) instead; this has the drawback of being annoyingly difficult to type, so Leipzig recommends a plain ASCII equals sign.)

Answer (score 1):

Your question applies to languages written in cuneiform.
Sumerian "blocks" are separated by points => su.zi.an.na
Cuneiform "blocks" are separated by hyphens => wa-a-ar-ta-an
Morphemic analyses are (usually) written with = signs.
Personally I find these = signs ugly and useless. Hyphens are just ok.

Comment: Not only languages written in cuneiform. Ainu uses = too to separate morphemes.